# Spark Scala read custom file format to dataframe with schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have an input file which looks much like csv but with custom header:

```
FIELDS-START
field1
field2
field3
FIELDS-END-DATA-START
val1,2,3
val2,4,5
DATA-END
```

Task:
To read data to a typed dataframe, schema is obtained dynamically, example for this specific file:

```
val schema = StructType(
  StructField("field1", StringType, true) ::
    StructField("field2", IntegerType, true) ::
    StructField("field3", IntegerType, true) :: Nil
)
```

So bacause of custom header I can't use spark csv reader. Other thing I tried:

```
val file = spark.sparkContext.textFile(...)
val data: RDD[List[String]] = file.filter(_.contains(",")).map(_.split(',').toList)

val df: DataFrame = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(data.map(Row.fromSeq(_)), schema)
```

It fails with runtime exception

> *java.lang.String is not a valid external type for schema of int* which is because *createDataFrame* doesn't do any casting.

**NOTE: Schema is obtained at runtime**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you expect to use this format a lot, you can write your own format deriving it from CsvRelation (see https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/csv/CsvRelation.scala). You will need to override the method `inferSchema` to read the schema from the first n lines instead of only the first.

Comment: what do you mean by schema is obtained at runtime?

Comment: Taken from schema registry.